# Do Pauli Matrices along with identity form a closed group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, group-theory

I tried to construct the multiplication table for $G=\{I, \sigma_{i}\}$, where $\sigma_{i}$ are the [Pauli Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices). Below is my multiplication table:

[image]

This table is **not** right. They are missing factors of $i$. We all know that Pauli Matrices form closed commutation relations, but their table doesn't seem to be closed? Isn't it necessary that operators with closed commutation relations form a closed group as well or vice versa?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_group

Comment: @zabop Perhaps you or the OP should summarize the obvious facts of the Pauli group  in an answer for the use of future readers.

Comment: Cannot do it now but during next week I'll probably have time for that :)